# android studio "editor" is extremely slow

Tags: android-studio

When I delete a character it takes 10 seconds for the cursor to come back.
The help to an error marker takes up to 30 seconds.

I use Android Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

My computer is sufficiently dimensioned, that can not be the problem

Can someone please help me?

Comment: This update has really slowed down android studio google has to patch this your not alone I guess its slow for many people

Comment: Check Task Manager and look if android studio is hording on memory if not then maybe its the new patch.